# How to show ls path of the ls-piped-into-grep output?

Tags: linux, terminal

Does anyone know how to show the containing directory of an `ls` output command?

For example in the / I issue `ls -R | grep something` the output finds the file that matches the something without telling me where the file is located, or it's full path.

Comment: `pwd` gives you the current directory

Answer (score 0):

According to "ls" command,you can only search for files in the current directory, For global search,please use the "find" command.